# How to get the uniform column width in DHTMLX bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, bar-chart, dhtmlx

What is the default width of each column in the DHTMLX bar chart.
I know that we can set the width of bar. But what is the default width of each column.

As I observed it depends on the total width of the chart. The larger the width of the chart, the larger the width of each column in width. Am I correct?
 If I am correct with the above statement, in my chart I giving the day number of the months as the X-axis values. the chart is drawing fine till the last day. For the last day I am getting too much space.
Please observe the space between 31 and 1.

Could you please tell me what would be the problem?

How can I get the uniform column width in my chart? Please advice

[image: Issue in the chart]

Answer (score 0):

Chart counts default width itself. It depens on common chart width (container dimention), items quantity, etc.

There is offset settings you can set empty fields "around" chart scale

Comment: Can you please tell me why I am getting extra wisth for thr last column?

I know that the chart will divide the total available width into number of columns. But for me the last column is getting more spaces as I showed in the image.
Could you please suggest me.

Comment: In this case i recommend you to attach demo on dhtmlx forum and ask staff to inspect it